# how to access data without saving attribute in table in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i have created a `attendance` scaffold, which has attribute `date` and `status`. now i want to make a search form. which takes duration(form_date,to_date) but i don't want to save duration in table, can i access attendance in that duration without saving it?

here is my form code:-
index.html.erb(Search)

```
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :from_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :from_date %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :to_date %>
    <%= form.date_select :to_date %>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to know if the `date` value of each `attendance` row falls between the `from_date` and `to_date`?

Comment: @Emu, yes i want to know ```status``` of each ```attendance``` row falls b/w ```from_date``` and ```to_date```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your form hits to a controller method to fetch the data:

```rb
def attendance
  @attendances = Attendance.where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', params[:from_date], params[:to_date])
end
```

Now, for this method, maybe you've a html file:

**attendance.html.erb**:

You can get all the attendances inside `@attendances`, where `date` falls between `from_date` and `to_date`. You can access the status via `@attendances.first.status` or a loop.